# GIMP fails to load

Tags: gimp

When I try to load GIMP, the splash screen flickers on, but disappears as soon as it shows.

When opening through terminal, the following error is displayed:

> GEGL-geglmodule.c-Message: Module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gegl-0.2/remap.so' load error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gegl-0.2/remap.so: undefined symbol: gegl_operation_point_composer3_get_type
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

All help is appreciated as using it soon is required. >.<

Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
Gimp version is 2.8

The following is an error I get when trying to 'Sudo apt-get upgrade'. This probably is related.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>   libopenal1 : Breaks: libopenal1:i386 (!= 1:1.14-4ubuntu1) but 1:1.13-4ubuntu3 is >installed
>   libopenal1:i386 : Depends: libopenal-data:i386 (= 1:1.13-4ubuntu3)
>                     Breaks: libopenal1 (!= 1:1.13-4ubuntu3) but 1:1.14-4ubuntu1 is >installed

Comment: Is it a custom build of `gimp`? I would guess that your version of gimp and the GEGL library version don't match - could you post the gimp version? Is it 2.6 or 2,8?

Comment: I can confirm that despite similar `undefined_symbol` errors, my `gimp` loads no problem.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: @mutzmatron - updated question

Comment: @JohnSGruber - updated question

Comment: Did this start to happen after a recent update?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @mutzmatron - well, recently I've had problems with dependencies. I'll update with the terminal error I receive when trying to update my software.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards - thank you for informing me of this. However, can I keep the question open for now? New information has been uncovered that it may be a problem regarding my dependencies. Until that is discovered to be the issue or not, would it be okay?

Comment: I just have one vote, which I've already cast. We'll see. In another note, I doubt `libopenal` has much to do with GIMP library error.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards - Thanks. I'll delete the question and set to asking how to deal with the other problem then. Who knows, it will probably be because I can't update and the GEGL is out of date...

Comment: Where were gimp 2.8 and libgegl-0.2 installed from? I see earlier versions in Precise myself.

Comment: @JohnSGruber - GIMP 2.8 was installed from a PPA provided for the newer release. Interestingly, in my Home folder, there is only a .gegl-0.0 folder...

Comment: It's always tricky to build more recent versions of software than your system officially supports, especially larger projects like gimp. It can become very difficult to meet all of the library dependencies without creating conflicts.

Comment: PPA's aren't really part of Ubuntu. You should probably pursue the issue with the owner of the PPA. They may know of the problem. It may simply not be compatible with 12.04.

Comment: While I agree that the PPA owner may be a good resource, *this question is not off-topic*. "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu" is *explicitly* [one of the things you can ask for help with, on this site](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). (Some PPA issues might be considered *too localized*, however.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to force install the dependencies using the following and let me know if that worked

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

restart the computer then try

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```